# Filereader API not updating file after first change

Tags: javascript, filereader

I've got the following code to change an image on file selection for use with cropper.js. This works great the first time I choose the file, however when I try changing the file the img doesn't update. Shouldn't onchange fire each time I change the file?

```
        document.getElementById("avatar").onchange = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
                document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;

                $('#image').cropper({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    preview: ".img-preview",
                    crop: function(e) {
                        // Output the result data for cropping image.
                        $('#x').val(e.x);
                        $('#y').val(e.y);
                        $('#w').val(e.width);
                        $('#h').val(e.height);
                    }
                });
            };

            // read the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        };
```

**UPDATE:** Apparently the filereader api is updating as I have expected functionality without the cropper. Where could I place the cropper.js booter so that it also updates with the img's source change?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this directly after onchange works perfectly.

```
if($('#image').cropper("active")) {
    $('#image').cropper("destroy");
}
```